# Need a regular expression to create friendly URLs

Tags: php, regex

Long time ago I asked almost the same thing but now I need more something more difficult. I need the same regex code to work for all the request ( if is possible )

So let's say I have the following:

```
$friendly = ''; to output /
$friendly = '/////'; to output /
$friendly = '///text//'; to output /text/
$friendly = '/text/?var=text'; to output /text/
$friendly = '/text/?var=text/'; to output /text/var-text/
$friendly = '/?text!@#$%^&*(()_+|/#anchor'; to output /text/
$friendly = '/!@#$%^&*(()_+|text/!@#$%^&*(()_+|text/'; to output /text/text/
```

Hope that make sense!

Comment: I don't understand - do you want that in a .htaccess?

Comment: And since your last question, have you attempted to learn regular expressions? [man](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) or [ri](http://regular-expressions.info/) - Just posting requirements and asking for codes is off-topic.

Comment: For the first couple of examples you dont need regular expressions. You can use something like "echo '/' . trim($friendly, '/');". But i would say you could use parse_url the string and then choose what you need.

Comment: @narcisradu because was not 100% working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a combination of [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace), [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) and [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/rtrim) will help here.

```
$values = array(
    ''                                        => '/'
  , '/////'                                   => '/'
  , '///text//'                               => '/text/'
  , '/text/?var=text'                         => '/text/'
  , '/text/?var=text/'                        => '/text/var-text/'
  , '/?text!@#$%^&*(()_+|/#anchor'            => '/text/'
  , '/!@#$%^&*(()_+|text/!@#$%^&*(()_+|text/' => '/text/text/'
);

foreach( $values as $raw => $expected )
{
  /* Remove '#'s that don't appear to be document fragments and anything
   *  else that's not a letter or one of '?' or '='.
   */
  $url = preg_replace(array('|(?<!/)#|', '|[^?=#a-z/]+|i'), '', $raw);

  /* Pull out the path and query strings from the resulting value. */
  $path  = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
  $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

  /* Ensure the path ends with '/'. */
  $friendly = rtrim($path, '/') . '/';

  /* If the query string ends with '/', append it to the path. */
  if( substr($query, -1) == '/' )
  {
    /* Replace '=' with '-'. */
    $friendly .= str_replace('=', '-', $query);
  }

  /* Clean up repeated slashes. */
  $friendly = preg_replace('|/{2,}|', '/', $friendly);

  /* Check our work. */
  printf(
    'Raw: %-42s - Friendly: %-18s (Expected: %-18s) - %-4s'
      , "'$raw'"
      , "'$friendly'"
      , "'$expected'"
      , ($friendly == $expected) ? 'OK' : 'FAIL'
  );
  echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

The above code outputs:

```
Raw: ''                                         - Friendly: '/'                (Expected: '/'               ) - OK  
Raw: '/////'                                    - Friendly: '/'                (Expected: '/'               ) - OK  
Raw: '///text//'                                - Friendly: '/text/'           (Expected: '/text/'          ) - OK  
Raw: '/text/?var=text'                          - Friendly: '/text/'           (Expected: '/text/'          ) - OK  
Raw: '/text/?var=text/'                         - Friendly: '/text/var-text/'  (Expected: '/text/var-text/' ) - OK  
Raw: '/?text!@#$%^&*(()_+|/#anchor'             - Friendly: '/text/'           (Expected: '/text/'          ) - OK  
Raw: '/!@#$%^&*(()_+|text/!@#$%^&*(()_+|text/'  - Friendly: '/text/text/'      (Expected: '/text/text/'     ) - OK
```

Note that this code does pass based on the examples you provided, but it might not properly capture the intent of what you are trying to accomplish.  I've commented the code to explain what it does so that you can adjust it where necessary.

For your reference:

- [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url)
- [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace)
- [`printf()`](http://php.net/printf)
- [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/rtrim)
- [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace)
- [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr)